# Create shortcut key trigger on slash (/) to go to the search box

Tags: feature-request, search, keyboard-shortcuts

I'd like it if hitting the slash key (<kbd>/</kbd>) would go to the search box, like it does in Gmail and Vim.

I could then type my query after doing:

1. Ctrl + T
2. www.stackoverflow.com
3. search query

and mousing to the search box wouldn't break my typing flow.

Comment: It's the first tab in Opera to get to the search box. `/` is the on page find tool.

Answer (score 1):

As Random pointed out tab does just what I want. Don't know why I didn't think of that...

Comment: Did not know you were even using Opera if that was the case

Comment: I use Chrome, but your solution worked the same :)

Comment: It should work in any browser which supports `tabindex`.